# Unity3d - прозрачность изображения

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать изображение более прозрачным (alpha)? Интересуют два подхода скриптом и в среде Unity.

Comment: Какой компонент используется? В цвете есть регулирование прозранчости

Comment: Я создал Sprite Renderer ,где через Sprite добавляю картинку. Кстати, говоря, картинка - это круг (о) цвета аквамарин, так что, если есть другой способ цветом, то картинку можно заменить на цвет будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через редактор:

В компоненте **Sprite Renderer** нажми на **Color** . Затем ползунком меняй параметр **A**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через скрипт:

```
 var sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 sr.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);// (r,g,b,a); последний параметр прозрачность. От 0 до 1.
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html

Answer (score 1):

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
```

Там где 0.5f задается альфа канал цвета. В данном случае 0.5 значит 50% прозрачности. 1f - не прозрачный (0%). 0f - полностью прозрачный (100%).